# regular expression

Tags: regex

This regular expression `/^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1))*S(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1{2})){3,30}\` not working. Why?

I need a string:

- length between 3 and 30 - `{3,30}`
- no to repeating the first letter more than once - `/^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1))`
- no to the repetition of the same letter more than two consecutive times - `/^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1{2}))`
- after the first three letters there can be only one space

E.G.

- "**ii**oy" no;
- "ioy" yes;
- "ioyy" yes;
- "io**yyy**tt" no;
- "ioy ycgu" yes;
- "ioy ycgu fdt" no;
- "ioy **yy**cgu" no;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look if it satisfies your requirements:

```
^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1))(?!.* .* )(?:([A-Za-z ])(?!\2{2})){2,29}$
```

Your reference to the second captured group was wrong: `\1` instead of `\2`.
Other than that I excluded spaces in the second negative lookahead.
I also fixed the length since the quantifier doesn't apply to your first group.

You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/Y1AT1L/1

Comment: If I wanted a space after the first three letters. Is it possible to insert it?
Space should be optional.

Comment: Actually I could have sworn it was in... Updated my answer with link to regex101

Comment: Moved the negative lookahead for spaces after the first character. (it was causing false positive for `ud jsid dj` )